# Add external client admin account to Outlook

Tags: server, outlook, office365, exchange-server, mdm

Something appears not to work in Exchange. What I want to do at the moment is the following:

I have a client and at the client I have an admin account where I also have a mailbox from. I want to add that mailbox in my personal Outlook application but that doesn't work. I am called for verification where I have to enter # but after hanging up I get the following error: "you have no access from here". What strange is that I can log in via the web version. But adding my mailbox to Outlook application does not work. Is it the MDM settings or is it something else? anyone have any idea?